# How can I stop emails being sent automatically to followers when a record is created?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

Whenever I create a record like in subscription or change the states in the record, a mail is triggered to the followers present in record with the logs. How to stop sending these mails automatically which picks up the logs created in the form view?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `create()` of `mail.thread` where this comes from:

```py
    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        """ Chatter override :
            - subscribe uid
            - subscribe followers of parent
            - log a creation message
        """
        if self._context.get('tracking_disable'):
            return super(MailThread, self).create(values)

        # subscribe uid unless asked not to
        if not self._context.get('mail_create_nosubscribe'):
            message_follower_ids = values.get('message_follower_ids') or []  # webclient can send None or False
            message_follower_ids += self.env['mail.followers']._add_follower_command(self._name, [], {self.env.user.partner_id.id: None}, {}, force=True)[0]
            values['message_follower_ids'] = message_follower_ids
        thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)

        # automatic logging unless asked not to (mainly for various testing purpose)
        if not self._context.get('mail_create_nolog'):
            doc_name = self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', self._name)]).read(['name'])[0]['name']
            thread.message_post(body=_('%s created') % doc_name)

        # auto_subscribe: take values and defaults into account
        create_values = dict(values)
        for key, val in self._context.iteritems():
            if key.startswith('default_') and key[8:] not in create_values:
                create_values[key[8:]] = val
        thread.message_auto_subscribe(create_values.keys(), values=create_values)

        # track values
        if not self._context.get('mail_notrack'):
            if 'lang' not in self._context:
                track_thread = thread.with_context(lang=self.env.user.lang)
            else:
                track_thread = thread
            tracked_fields = track_thread._get_tracked_fields(values.keys())
            if tracked_fields:
                initial_values = {thread.id: dict.fromkeys(tracked_fields, False)}
                track_thread.message_track(tracked_fields, initial_values)

        return thread
```

As you can see there are some context flags to handle such situations. For your requirment `mail_create_nolog` should be used:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    return super(MyModel, self.with_context(mail_create_nolog=1)).create(vals)
```

Comment: So if I add this method sale subscription, then I won't be getting the mails?

Comment: You can also use `mail_create_nosubscribe` to tell Odoo not to subscribe the creating user to the new thread (in your case a subscription). Or if you want to disable the whole thread features on creation just use `tracking_disable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings->technical settings->subtype->disable the notification for your model.

In your case, for sale.subscription, Just disable the model by clicking the default checkbox.